# Auto-rename 5,000+ filenames and maintain filename consistency with excel file

Tags: windows, filenames

I'm sorry I don't know how to word this well. I'm wondering if this is possible.

- I have a folder of files
- I have an excel file with a column that contains the filenames.

I want to be able to change the filename on both the excel file and the filename to something different (but so that the filename and excel are the same).

Specifically I want to add a six character alphanumerical string to the end of each file (so filename.pdf -> filename081ad3.pdf)

Possible Issues:

-The folder with files has many subfolders with files I also want to change

-There are 'extra' files in the directory that aren't on the excel sheet and that I don't want to change the filename to.

I honestly don't even know where to start with this issue. I think I could somehow use advanced renamer, but then I don't know how to work that in with the excel file.

Any Ideas?

Comment: So the logic is read the first entry in the excel. Then look for the file. If it exists append 6 character string to both filename and excel entry. Move to next excel entry. Repeat. Is this right?

Comment: There is no simple answer to your question. I don't think there's a "tool" that can do what you want exactly. you'll have do a little bit of scripting/programming. If I were you, here's what I'll do: 1) I add a column to my Excel, write a formula to calculate new file name 2) I add another column, write a formula to create a command. I copy this column and create a batch file.

Answer (score -1):

You'd need to edit (search & replace) the column of file names inside Excel, and rename the files outside (by a bit of scripting).